# Installing the "correct" debuginfo-kernel package on CentOS 6.0

Tags: centos

I have CentOS 6.0 server, which comes with kernel 2.6.32-71.  When I instaled debuginfo-kernel rpm package (which contains the debug kernel) using yum from the centos repository, the debug kernel for kernel 2.6.32-279.2.1 got installed, which I am guessing is for CentOS 6.3.

How can I get yum to install the debuginfo-kernel package for the kerenl running in CentOS 6.0?

On a CentOS server how can I get the full kernel version number.  "uname -r" only gives me "partial" release number.

## > uname -r

2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64

I need the additional two numbers after "71", so I can manually download the rpm packages and install them myself.

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Answer (score 1):

The information is in rpms:

```
rpm -qa | grep ^kernel
```

Comment: The output of rpm -qa does not show the full version of the kernel, and adds more to the confusion


$ uname -r
2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64
$ rpm -qa | grep ^kernel
kernel-firmware-2.6.32-71.el6.noarch
kernel-2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64  <== Current version installed.
kernel-headers-2.6.32-220.7.1.el6.x86_64  <= Not sure why *-220 is installed.
kernel-debuginfo-2.6.32-279.2.1.el6.centos.plus.x86_64
kernel-devel-2.6.32-220.7.1.el6.x86_64  <= Not sure why *-220 is installed 
kernel-debuginfo-common-x86_64-2.6.32-279.2.1.el6.centos.plus.x86_64
$

Comment: There has been a renaming of kernel debug packages between 6.0 and 6.3. The rpm you may be looking for may be found here: http://vault.centos.org/6.0/os/x86_64/Packages/kernel-debug-devel-2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64.rpm

Comment: I need to install the debuginfo-kernel package for now, and not hte devel package.  Hence I need the exact kernel version.  Any other way to find that out since rpm -qa was not helpful.

Comment: You don't seem to understand my answer. Maybe the simplest thing to do for you would be to cleanly upgrade to 6.3 because for now, you have a mix of 6.0 ams 6.3 rpms in your install

Answer (score 0):

The exact same thing happened to me, please follow the steps in my answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/527525/centos-server-rebooted-unexpectedly-and-im-unable-to-process-crash-file-what-a/527553#527553) in order to fix your issue.